# How do I send a vCard using Kinkler41/android-smsmms library?

Tags: android, sms, mms, vcf-vcard

I'm using [EZ VCard library](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) to build a vCard and create a `.vcf` file. Then, using [Kinkler41/android-smsmms library](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms) I want to send this vCard through sms/mms. What is the correct way to do it?